# what does -w specifies in perl script process execution

Tags: linux, perl, ps, rhel6

When I was checking processes of perl using `ps aux | grep perl` the list of perl pid's got listed where its waiting in queue. so i started investigating how this processes got initiated `/usr/local/bin/processLogs`. I wanted to know what does `-w`  meant in this process execution `/usr/bin/perl -w /usr/local/bin/processLogs`.

```
[root@test]# ps aux | grep perl
root      4223  1.6  0.0 132560  4576 ?        R    03:11   1:06 /usr/bin/perl -w /usr/local/bin/processLogs
root      4233  1.3  0.0 132560  4552 ?        R    03:11   0:55 /usr/bin/perl -w /usr/local/bin/processLogs
root      4246  1.1  0.0 132560  4552 ?        R    03:11   0:49 /usr/bin/perl -w /usr/local/bin/processLogs
root      4259  1.0  0.0 132560  4548 ?        R    03:11   0:44 /usr/bin/perl -w /usr/local/bin/processLogs
root      4272  0.8  0.0 132560  4544 ?        R    03:11   0:33 /usr/bin/perl -w /usr/local/bin/processLogs
root      4288  0.6  0.0 132560  4580 ?        R    03:11   0:28 /usr/bin/perl -w /usr/local/bin/processLogs
```

Comment: `man perl` works.  Most commands in Linux provide a manual page.  The `-w` may be on the shebang line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run `perl -h` you will get the help menu, where it says for `-w`:

```
  -w                enable many useful warnings
```

This simply enables warnings. If this program is run in an automatic process, the warnings may be redirected to a log where you can read them. Assuming there are any warnings. You will need to refer to the program file `processLogs` to see what the program does.

Typically, an experienced user will not use `-w`, but prefer to use the lexically scoped `use warnings` instead.

The full output:

```
$ perl -h

Usage: perl [switches] [--] [programfile] [arguments]
  -0[octal]         specify record separator (\0, if no argument)
  -a                autosplit mode with -n or -p (splits $_ into @F)
  -C[number/list]   enables the listed Unicode features
  -c                check syntax only (runs BEGIN and CHECK blocks)
  -d[:debugger]     run program under debugger
  -D[number/list]   set debugging flags (argument is a bit mask or alphabets)
  -e program        one line of program (several -e's allowed, omit programfile)
  -E program        like -e, but enables all optional features
  -f                don't do $sitelib/sitecustomize.pl at startup
  -F/pattern/       split() pattern for -a switch (//'s are optional)
  -i[extension]     edit <> files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
  -Idirectory       specify @INC/#include directory (several -I's allowed)
  -l[octal]         enable line ending processing, specifies line terminator
  -[mM][-]module    execute "use/no module..." before executing program
  -n                assume "while (<>) { ... }" loop around program
  -p                assume loop like -n but print line also, like sed
  -s                enable rudimentary parsing for switches after programfile
  -S                look for programfile using PATH environment variable
  -t                enable tainting warnings
  -T                enable tainting checks
  -u                dump core after parsing program
  -U                allow unsafe operations
  -v                print version, patchlevel and license
  -V[:variable]     print configuration summary (or a single Config.pm variable)
  -w                enable many useful warnings
  -W                enable all warnings
  -x[directory]     ignore text before #!perl line (optionally cd to directory)
  -X                disable all warnings
```

> Run ['perldoc perl'](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun) for more help with Perl.